# How to update copyright text of footer in magento 2.2.0 dev version

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to update the copyright text of footer in Magento 2.2, but I am not getting any option to update this text from admin. I follow the below steps

stores-> configuration -> general -> design

But here I am not getting any footer option so that I can update the copyright text.

Answer (score -2):

Content -> Configuration -> (edit default/website/store) -> Footer -> Copyright